# Filter list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of data that is stored locally and I use to filter the list using text input from the user.

```js
 var userData = {
     "product": [
          { "name":"cannon",
            "type":"camera",
            "serialno":"c123",
            "stock":10,
            "img":"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff",
            "Description":"blablabla"
          },
          { "name":"cannon2",
            "type":"camera2",
            "serialno":"c124",
            "stock":1,
            "img":"http://placehold.it/400x250/fff/000",
            "Description":"blablabla"
          }
          ]                                
                   };

                if (event.keyCode != 13){
                        var isFound = false;
                        for(var i=0;i<userData.product.length;i++){                             
                            var strings = userData.product[i].name.split(" ");
                            for(var string in strings){ 
                                if(strings[string].startsWith(data)){
                                    result += openTag +userData.product[i].name+closeTag;
                                    isFound=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }                           
                        }

                        if(!isFound){
                            result = openTag + "No Result Found" +closeTag;
                            console.log(result);                    
                        }
                }
```

Here i archive the filter with using loop but i just want to know which is best way to filter out the list.

Comment: How are you searching? Paste the code you used.

Comment: i mean i want it!!

Comment: Use https://lunrjs.com/

Comment: Still, you need to show more code. Where would that searching code go? The way you have it right now, pretty much ***any*** answer would be guesswork.

Comment: well not sure how you are not going to do it without a loop.

Comment: what about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Unless you want to pay us but even then you'd need to contract us through other means rather than this website.

Comment: @vlaz see post again. Every developer have pride what yours!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mind all the negativity and use [Lunr](https://lunrjs.com/) or [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index/). They are both highly capable search engines that can run in the browser.

If the index doesn't change or you have few documents/items, use Lunr. If you have changes to your index often or many documents/items, use search-index.

Disclaimer: I work a little with search-index.

Comment: Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just done this by using HTML element select, I just add every value to a select option that's all HTML took the search for me.